# Create groups from an unstructured data array using Ramda or similar

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, javascript-objects, ramda.js

Given an array with objects of this form:

```
[{data: {set: 'set1', option: 'option1'}},
 {data: {set: 'set1', option: 'option2'}},
 {data: {set: 'set1', option: 'option3'}},
 {data: {set: 'set2', option: 'optionA'}},
 {data: {set: 'set2', option: 'optionB'}}]
```

How can I get an array that looks like this:

```
[{set: 'set1', options: ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']},
 {set: 'set2', options: ['optionA', 'optionB']}]
```

I would like to use functional programming, Ramda or native JS methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to think about questions like this in terms of a few steps that keep moving me toward my desired output.  Sometimes this means that I miss a more elegant solution, but it usually makes it easier to come up with something that works.

So let's look at your problem this way using Ramda.

---

### Step 1: Remove unnecessary data

You don't want that outer `data` property.  Since your data is a list of objects, and each one has a single `data` property holding the data we want, we can simply call [`prop('data')`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#prop) on each one.

To call it on each one, we can use [`map`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map), giving us `map(prop('data'))`.

Because this is such a common use, Ramda also supplies a function which combines `map` and `prop` this way: [`pluck('data')`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pluck).  Applying that to your input we get:

```
[
  {option: "option1", set: "set1"},
  {option: "option2", set: "set1"},
  {option: "option3", set: "set1"},
  {option: "optionA", set: "set2"}
  {option: "optionB", set: "set2"}
]
```

This is a good start.  Now we need to think about combining them into like groups.

### Step 2: Grouping the data

We want all the elements that share their `set` property to be grouped together.  Ramda offers [`groupBy`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy), which accepts a function that turns an item into a grouping key.  We want to group by that `set` property, so we can use `prop` again, and call `groupBy(prop('set'))` against the previous results.

This yields:

```
{
  set1: [
    {option: "option1", set: "set1"},
    {option: "option2", set: "set1"},
    {option: "option3", set: "set1"},
  ],
  set2: [
    {option: "optionA", set: "set2"}
    {option: "optionB", set: "set2"}
  ]
}
```

There is redundant information in there.  Somewhere we're going to need to figure that out.  But I'll save that for a little bit while I try to pull together other parts.

### Step 3: Combine the options

We've already seen `pluck`.  It looks like we could use it on `set1` and `set2`.  Well `map` also works on objects, so if we simply call `map(pluck('option'))` on that last we get this:

```
{
  set1: ["option1", "option2", "option3"], 
  set2: ["optionA", "optionB"]
}
```

Oh look, that also got rid of the redundancy.  This is looking pretty close to the desired output.

### Step 4: Rebuilding Objects

But now I don't see a built-in Ramda function that will get me all the way there.  I could write a custom one.  Or I could look to convert this in two steps.  Knowing that I would like to use Ramda's [`zipObj`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipObj) function, I can first convert the above to arrays via [`toPairs`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#toPairs), generating this:

```
[
  ["set1", ["option1", "option2", "option3"]], 
  ["set2", ["optionA", "optionB"]]
]
```

and then I can map `zipObj` over the results with the keys I want each property to have.  That means I can call `map(zipObj(['set', 'options']))` to get the final desired results:

```
[
  {
    set: "set1",
    options: ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
  },
  {
    set: "set2",
    options: ["optionA", "optionB"]
  }
]
```

### Step 5: Putting it all together

All right, now we have to put these together.  Ramda has [`pipe`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe) and [`compose`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose).  I usually choose `compose` only when it fits on one line.  So merging these with `pipe`, we can write this:

```
const transform = pipe(
  pluck('data'),
  groupBy(prop('set')),
  map(pluck('option')),
  toPairs,
  map(zipObj(['set', 'options']))
)
```

And then just call it as

```
transform(myObj)
```

---

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?console.clear%28%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20data%20%3D%20%5B%7Bdata%3A%20%7Bset%3A%20%27set1%27%2C%20option%3A%20%27option1%27%7D%7D%2C%0A%20%7Bdata%3A%20%7Bset%3A%20%27set1%27%2C%20option%3A%20%27option2%27%7D%7D%2C%0A%20%7Bdata%3A%20%7Bset%3A%20%27set1%27%2C%20option%3A%20%27option3%27%7D%7D%2C%0A%20%7Bdata%3A%20%7Bset%3A%20%27set2%27%2C%20option%3A%20%27optionA%27%7D%7D%2C%0A%20%7Bdata%3A%20%7Bset%3A%20%27set2%27%2C%20option%3A%20%27optionB%27%7D%7D%5D%0A%0Aconst%20transform%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20pluck%28%27data%27%29%2C%0A%20groupBy%28prop%28%27set%27%29%29%2C%0A%20map%28pluck%28%27option%27%29%29%2C%0A%20toPairs%2C%0A%20map%28zipObj%28%5B%27set%27%2C%20%27options%27%5D%29%29%0A%29%0A%0Atransform%28data%29)**.  On there you can comment out later lines inside the `pipe` to see what the earlier ones do.

I built the code there, adding one line at a time to the pipe until I had transformed the data.  I think this is a nice way to work.